# imread function not working for .PNG on windows

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to show image using

```
Mat_<float> depth_image_16_bit = imread(path_to_image, -1);
```

but it can not be loaded. It show assertion error.
It works for `Mat` but not for `short` or `float`.

Answer (score 1):

If in the `imread` you use the parameter `-1`, which is equivalent to `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, you get a 8 bit image with the original number of channels.

So if your image is:

- single channel, you get a `Mat1b` (aka `Mat_<uchar>`)
- 3 channels, you get a `Mat3b` (aka `Mat_Vec3b`)
- 4 channels, you get a `Mat4b` (aka `Mat_Vec4b`)

So you can check the type and numbers of channels of your `Mat`, and then change to correct `Mat_<Tp>`:

```
Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cout << img.channels();
cout << img.depth() << endl;
```

---

Or you can convert it to `float` after you loaded it:

```
Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
img.convertTo(img, CV_32F); // now your image is of CV_32F type
```

---

Or, you can load it with correct depth (this is useful if your image has 2 bytes per pixels):

```
 Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
 cout << img.channels();
 cout << img.depth() << endl;
```